Access denied when not run as admin
I wrote a Powershell script in order to add a group inside our local Administrators group.
To run the "Add-LocalGroupMember" command, I am using psexec.exe inside my powershell script to run this command as our local Admin account. The script is working perfectly, but only if I run ISE or the script as Administrator. I don't understand why it is not working without Admin rights because it should use my local Admin account to run the command...
Please find below my small script, of course, I removed sensible information, but you should be able to understand the principle of this script :)
#Retreiving local admin group name (can be Administrators or Administrateurs depending of the PC language)
$groupeAdminLocal = Get-LocalGroup | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*admin*" -and $_.Description -notlike "*Hyper*" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#Group I would like to add niside my local Admin group
$adAdminGroup = "Computer-Admins-Group"

#Retreiving local admin account name (can be Administrator or Administrateur depentding of the PC language)
$username = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $groupeAdminLocal | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "FRD*" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#If no Administrator or Administrateur accounts found, we use "guestaccount" (specific case from my environment, local Admin account may have been renamed)
if (-not $username) {
    $username = "guestaccount"
}

$admin = $username.Split("\")
$admin = $admin[1]
$username = ".\" + $admin

#First part of the local admin password
$sVisAdminFirstPartPass = "Localpass1"

#Path where is stored the last part of the local admin password
$regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
$regValueName = "LegalNoticeTest"

#We get the content of the registry key
$regContent = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath).$regValueName
$regContent = $regContent -replace '\s+', ' '

#Regex to look for the string inside parenthesis (second part of the password)
$pattern = '\(([^)]+)\)'
$matches = [regex]::matches($regContent, $pattern)
if ($matches.Count -gt 0) {
    $lastMatch = $matches[$matches.Count - 1].Groups[1].Value
    $password = $sVisAdminFirstPartPass + $lastMatch #this line is used to assemble the password (first part + second part located inside the registry)
}

#I declare the command to be run as a local admin
$sScriptCommand = Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $groupeAdminLocal -Member $adAdminGroup
$sCommand = "\psexec.exe /accepteula -u " + $username + " -p " + $password + " " + $sScriptCommand

#I run a new process to run the above command
Start-Process powershell $sCommand

The only error i'm getting is :
Add-LocalGroupMember : Access denied.
I think I am missing something, but I can't figure out what...
The result should be that the script is working without running it with admin rights.

$sScriptCommand = Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $groupeAdminLocal -Member $adAdminGroup does not declare or store the Add-LocalGroupMember commandline, it executes the  commandline and stores the execution result in $sScriptCommand. Since this happens while you're still in user mode you get access denied.

Hello @Halfix, thanks for the clarification, I just did some tests with:
$sScriptCommand = "Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $groupeAdminLocal -Member $adAdminGroup"
I verified with the $sScriptCommand and I got my full command now displaying correctly without the quotes. Now I have no error launching it without admin rights, but it simply does nothing without any error...

Leaving the syntax problems aside, I don't think you can create an elevated process  (as another user) with psexec from a non-elevated process. Creating an elevated process with psexec requires the -h option, which in turn requires the caller to be elevated.

Try the -Credential parameter of Start-Process. This is the common way to fire a sub-process using a different account - no need for a detour via psexec.exe

@Halfix: True (providing full credentials, i.e. avoiding a password prompt, is more involved when using Start-Process, though). Neither solution allows automated elevation, however, which is what is being asked for (unless UAC is disabled, which is strongly discouraged - see this answer).

@mklement0 Please read the OP carefully: It says "... run this command as our local Admin account ...", so this is about using a different account for a sub-process and not about UAC elevation of the current executing account.

Hello, following your advices, I removed psexec.exe and tried to only use Start-Process.
What I did different is to create a PS Credential object stored inside $credentials :
When I display $credentials, I got my username displaying correctly (.\username) and password showing as "System.Security.SecureString".
Then, to run my command, I tried like this :
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-Command "Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $groupeAdminLocal -Member $adAdminGroup "'
Now, I have no more errors but now, it just does nothing...

Hello again, I just made more tests by changing the syntax of my Start-Process command and now it is actually working as excepted! My final command now looks like :
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList "Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $groupeAdminLocal -Member $adAdminGroup "
I initially asked ChatGPT to help me with this command but it wasn't a great idea haha. I don't know where came the -Command but removing it actually fixed my issue.
Now my script is adding my group correctly as local admin, without needing any elevation from std user, thanks all!

@Halfix: Please read the OP even more carefully: The script calls Add-LocalGroupMember, which requires elevation. That this elevation should occur in the context of a different user is incidental to the fact that elevation must occur, and UAC cannot be bypassed (unless you open up serious security holes). As for how achieve elevation as a different user in PowerShell: you need nested Start-Process calls: see this answer.

@ProdzzPerfect, while your Start-Process call is syntactically correct, I wouldn't expect it to work, because the target process is created without elevation, which you need for Add-LocalGroupMember to succeed (it would only work if (the target user is an admin and) you disabled UAC altogether, which is strongly discouraged).

@mklement0, I just did the test with a standard user PC, without any admin rights and it's actually working fine... As I wrote it in my previous comment, I am running the Start-Process with -Credential $credentials as $credentials contains local administrator username and password. Then, the Start-Process is executing my Add-LocalGroupMember and it works fine. I didn't disabled UAC at all or any other security feature on the user machine.

@ProdzzPerfect, You're (ultimately) running as the administrator with the built-in account literally named Administrator (on English machines) - I missed that originally. This account indeed automatically runs with elevation. As such, it bypasses UAC, even when UAC is otherwise in effect, and therefore is a security risk and shouldn't be used, which is the reason it is disabled by default.


Indeed, Start-Process, with its -Credential parameter, is sufficient to launch a process as a different user in PowerShell - no need for the (download-on-demand) psexec utility.

Your intent is to ultimately call Add-LocalGroupMember, which requires elevation (running with administrative privileges), whereas you're running with a non-administrative account, whose sessions are by definition always non-elevated.

Under normal circumstances, with UAC (User Account Control) in effect (which is strongly recommended), even administrative users run non-elevated sessions by default and requesting elevation involves an interactive prompt that by deliberate design cannot be programmatically responded to.

Therefore - with the one exception discussed below - starting a process as a different user even with the credentials of an administrative user does not result in an elevated process; if you need to run as a different user and with elevation, you need a two-step process:

Launch an intermediate process as the target user...

... and, from that process, request launching an elevated process (as that user, by default), which then invariably triggers the UAC prompt that cannot be automated.

This answer shows this approach, using nested Start-Process calls, but note that automating launching the intermediate process is a security concern for the same reasons discussed below.



Even though you say that UAC is enabled on your system, you're still effectively bypassing UAC through ill-advised use of the built-in administrative account named Administrator (on English systems; the specific, potentially localized name can be obtained with (Get-LocalUser | Where-Object Sid -like S-1-5-21-*-500).Name)

With UAC enabled, this is the only account for which an elevated processes are invariably created, without prompting; to put it differently: this special account is exempt from UAC.

Thus, with programmatically constructed credentials for the Administrator user passed to Start-Process -Credential, you can - but shouldn't - fully automate your (ultimate) call to Add-LocalGroupMember from a non-elevated session.

As an aside: Storing passwords in the registry, as you seem to be doing, is ill-advised due to lack of encryption. And even if you store it encrypted, your desire to run the code from a non-administrative account means that said account needs access to the decrypted form too.



The reason you shouldn't do that is that it defeats the purpose of UAC, which is designed to require a credentialed human to interactively authorize launching an elevated process.

For this reason, the built-in Administrator account is disabled by default.






The secure, but less convenient approach is therefore to simply request elevation with -Verb RunAs (which can not be combined with -Credential), which, if running as a non-administrative user, will trigger a UAC prompt in which you'll have to interactively provide the credentials of an administrator; if running as an administrative user, you'll get a simple yes/no prompt to authorize the elevation:
Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe "Add-LocalGroupMember -Group \`"$groupeAdminLocal\`" -Member \`"$adAdminGroup\`""

